# Creating multiple images with php

Tags: php, image

So I have a file named "names.txt" with multiple lines. Each line contains one name.
I also have one mockup image named "participant.jpg"

And here it`s my code:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("names.txt", "r");

function create_img($line)
{
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("./images/participant.jpg");
    $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

    // Write the string at the top left
    imagettftext($im, 50, 0, 80, 640, $textcolor, 'nexa.ttf', $line);

    imagejpeg($im, './uploads/' . $line . '.jpg');
    imagedestroy($im);
}

if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        create_img($line);
    }
} else {
    die('Cannot open file..');
}
?>
```

So for every new line I want to create a specific photo and "upload" it to my uploads folder.

It only creates the image for the last line and for the rest it returns me this error:

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [<a href='function.imagejpeg'>function.imagejpeg</a>]: Unable to open './uploads/Botond.jpg' for writing: Invalid argument in C:\lab\ccc-badges\badges.php on line 12
```

This is some $line outputs

```
Alina Popescu
Adrian Oltean
Patricia-Andrada Leven
Stanescu Gheorghe
```

Comment: try to create new file with name `'./uploads/'.$line.'.jpg'` before line 12

Comment: wat's the difference between last line and other lines?

Comment: no difference .. just that is the last the line

Comment: can you please show some outputs of `$line` aspecially the last one? I mean `echo $line,'<br>';`

Comment: edited now .. please check

Comment: and it's always `Botond.jpg`?

Comment: no, from my example of $line outputs it will create only "Stanescu Gheorghe.jpg" and for all the rest will return me that error.. (so i will have 3 errors and one succesfully created image)

Comment: Oh, I understood. That's because the trailing `newline` of each `fgets`, except the last one. =)

Comment: is there any method to solve my problem ?

Comment: yeah, use `imagejpeg($im, './uploads/' . trim($line) . '.jpg');` when writing in a file

Comment: thank you... didn`t need it anymore but it works .. i would like to choose you as Best answer. . please leave a reply so i could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem because  the trailing `newline` of each `fgets()`, except the last line.

use `imagejpeg($im, './uploads/' . trim($line) . '.jpg');` when writing in a file.